# Partial search using wildcard in Elastic Search

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I want to search on array value in Elastic search using wildcard.

[image]

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "short_message": {
                "value": "*nne*",
                "boost": 1.0,
                "rewrite": "constant_score"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am search on "short_messages", It's working for me.
But I want to search on "messages.message" it's not working.

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "messages.message": {
                "value": "*nne*",
                "boost": 1.0,
                "rewrite": "constant_score"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I also want to search for multiple fields in an array.

For Example:-
fields: ["messages.message","messages.subject", "messages.email_search"]

It is possible then to give me the best solutions.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you add mapping and result of your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are making used of [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) datatype for `messages`.

You would need to make use of [`nested query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) for this:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "messages",
      "query": {
        "wildcard": {
          "messages.message": {
            "value": "*nne*",
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For multi-field querying, you can probably do it using `query_string` so basically your solution would be to make use of `query_string` inside a `nested query`.

### Query String:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "messages",
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": ["messages.message", "messages.subject"],
          "query": "*nne*",
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Query DSL

You can also make use of `wildcard` using `Query DSL` but then again, you need to add multiple query clauses for every field, for performance reasons I suspect that wildcard queries doesn't support multi-field querying.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "messages",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "wildcard": { 
                "messages.message": {
                  "value": "*nne*",
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "messages.subject": {
                  "value": "*nne*",
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that wildcard search is not advisable because of the number of regex operations it has to do and would affect your latency to get a response, instead I would recommend you to look into [Ngram Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) thereby which you can make use of a simple match query to get your desired result.

Let me know if this helps!